# How to associate a feature flag (define) with external library in CMake?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

`FindProtobuf.cmake` for Google Protocol Buffers creates a set of targets, for example `protobuf::libprotobuf-lite` one.

Now, in my project, I'm using this `protobuf::libprotobuf-lite` in `target_link_libraries`. And this works fine.

However, after upgrading to protobuf v3 I noticed that generated files have small blocks guarded by

```
#if LANG_CXX11
```

Yet, as it seems, this `LANG_CXX11` is not defined by `FindProtobuf.cmake`. It seems I have to define it on my own if I want to use C++11 features with protobuf-generated code.

Obviously, I could just do it globally and be done with it. However, I would much more prefer to somehow "bind" the `LANG_CXX11` with the `protobuf::libprotobuf-lite` target, so that I will get it whenever I used it and only where I use it.

`target_compile_definitions` will not work here since it doesn't accept imported targets while targets created by `FindProtobuf.cmake` are imported ones. And anyway, it seems like not the right thing to do.

The only idea I have for now (although not yet tested) is to create another custom target that would only link (`PUBLIC`) with `protobuf::libprotobuf-lite` and add the `LANG_CXX11` define (`PUBLIC` as well). Then I would use this custom target instead of `protobuf::libprotobuf-lite`. But it doesn't feel good either.

How to do it properly with CMake? (I'm on version 3.8 if it matters.)

Comment: You may append you definition to [INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) property. This property is actually filled by `target_compile_definitions(INTERFACE)`. (You are right that `target_compile_definitions` doesn't work with IMPORTED targets).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah... But since `target_compile_definitions` doesn't work with `IMPORTED` targets and `FindProtobuf.cmake` produces such an `IMPORTED` target than I cannot do it this way, right? (Otherwise then to start using my custom `FindProtobuf.cmake` which might set the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` directly - however this means maintencne burden.)

Comment: No, you may freely set that property even for IMPORTED target. Constraints on the function are not applied on the property it sets.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Many of your comments I've seen can easily be answers, such as this one. Why not answer instead of commenting?